# How can I include the value name in the title of the output file when executing a reg query?

Tags: batch-file

I am using the following reg query as a logon script to return versions of Office365 from users computers.

```
Reg Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\O365ProPlusRetail - en-us" /v DisplayVersion > "sharename\%ComputerName%.txt"
```

where sharename is the network location to store the logs. I want to add %ComputerName%.%DisplayVersion% to the title of each txt file so I can easily see what versions people are on. Is this possible? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Stuart

Comment: Where do you need `%ComputerName%.%DisplayVersion%` ?  What title do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the reg query command on each local machine and saving the output in a share location, you could connect to the remote registry and save the output locally from your server. Below code will pick up the remote hostnames from input.txt and queries the registry and saves the out in hostname.txt format. If you want to save the output in a single text with %hostname% , %reg_query_output% for you can modify the code.

```
for /f %%i in (input.txt) do (  
    Reg Query "\\%%i\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\O365ProPlusRetail - en-us" /v DisplayVersion >%%i.txt
    )
```

Cheers,
G

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible, you need to set the DisplayVersion to a variable first, here is the proposed code below:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\O365ProPlusRetail - en-us" /v DisplayVersion ^| findstr "DisplayVersion"') do set DisplayVersion=%%b
echo %computername%.%DisplayVersion% > "sharename\%computername%.%DisplayVersion%"
```

I havent tested it, but it should work